# Softmax and Hinge functions in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to implement the Hinge loss function in Python and faced with some misleadings.

In some sources that I used to read (for example, "Regression Analysis in Python"under Luca Massoron) states that Hinge sometimes calls as Softmax function.

But for me it is kind of strange because, Hinge:
[image]

and Softmax is just exponential function like: [image]

I made that function in Python (for Softmax) this way:

```
def softmax(x):
   e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
   return e_x/e_x.sum(axis=0)
```

Have two questions:

1. Can I use that softmax function like an equivalent to hinge function?
2. If not, how can hinge be implemented in Python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use that softmax function like an equivalent to hinge function?

no - they are not equivalent.

a hinge function is a loss function and do not provide well-calibrated probabilities, whereas softmax is a mapping function (one that maps a set of scores into a distribution, one that sums to one).

> If not, how can hinge be implemented in Python?

this following snippet captures the essence of hinge loss functions:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xmin, xmax = -1, 2
xx = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
plt.plot(xx, np.where(xx < 1, 1 - xx, 0), label="Hinge loss")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also implement softmax functions in pure python :)

```py
import numpy as np
import math as math

def sofyMax(data):
    # pure python 
    # math:: $rezult(powe,sumColumn) = \dfrac{powe(data)}{sumColumn(powe(data))}$
    
    def powe(data):
        outp = [[] for _ in range(len(data))]
        for column in range(len(data[0])):
            r = 0 
            for row in data:
                outp[r]+=[math.exp(row[column])]
                r+=1
        return outp

    def sumColumn(data):
        outps = []
        for column in range(len(data[0])):
            total = 0
            for row in data:
                total+=row[column]
            outps += [total]
        return outps
    
    def rezult(data,sumcolumn):
        outp = [[] for _ in range(len(data))]
        l = 0
        for row in data:
            for c,s in zip(row,sumcolumn) :
                outp[l] += [c/s]
            l+=1
        return outp
    
    
    
    et1 = powe(data)        
    et2 = sumColumn(et1)
    return rezult(et1,et2)
data = np.random.randn(10,5)

(np.exp(data)/np.sum(np.exp(data),axis=0)) == (np.array(sofyMax(data)))
```